# MacOS Catalina cannot find /usr/include file

Tags: macos, headers, macos-catalina

As I have upgraded my system to Catalina, I am not able to install /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg for the use of header files.

Is there any way to install macOS_10.15.pkg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple decided to remove `/usr/include` in Catalina. The reason is Xcode now supports multiple SDKs and multiple installations of Xcode. The SDKs are inside Xcode.app.

Depending of **why** you need the header files, the solution might be different. 
`xcrun --show-sdk-path` will show a default SDK path, but there may be others. For example, one possible path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk`. From there, `usr/include` holds common public headers.

See :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53171665/445757
- https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/xdebug-catalina-issue#the-catalina-issue

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about compiling a library that requires the header files, the solution is pretty simple, yet hard to find: You need to set the environment variable `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to 10.14 for Mojave and likely 10.15 for Catalina, like so

`export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.14`

Thanks to @ChristophSchmidl who gave this hint at:

https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/3710#issuecomment-575627844